# How to use cpan command to install downloaded perl module (.tar.gz file)

Tags: bash, software-installation, scripts, perl, cpan

I want to install Sys::RunAlone. I'm not able to install cpanm due to other independent reason, with which I was able to give the downloaded Sys::RunAlone compressed file directly and it installed. In case of cpan I've seen readme https://www.cpan.org/modules/by-module/CPAN/CPAN-2.25.readme where it shows how to install in a prompt, so I'm assuming there should be some way I should be able to install the perl module by directly giving the .tar.gz file to the cpan command as argument, instead of entering the prompt, so that I can directly call it from my shell script. If that is not possible there may be a way to enter prompt and give arguments (the downloaded perl module in the form of .tar.gz file) through the shell script itself.